# Group up the tags and change them into BIO format

Tags: python

Original text file:

```
Our _ 
tracing _ 
procedures _ 
take Method\_Tool[3] 
advantage Method\_Tool[3] 
of Method\_Tool[3] 
known Method\_Tool[3] 
structure Method\_Tool[3] 
lineage Problem[1] 
tracing Problem[1] 
problem Problem[1] 
in Problem[1]
```

How to group up the tag by their name ? change to BIO format.
The first tag would be B-xxx, and the rest of the same tag become I-xxx.
expected output:

```
Our _ 
tracing _ 
procedures _ 
take B-Method\_Tool
advantage I-Method\_Tool[3] 
of I-Method\_Tool[3] 
known I-Method\_Tool[3] 
structure I-Method\_Tool[3] 
lineage B-Problem[1] 
tracing I-Problem[1] 
problem I-Problem[1] 
in I-Problem[1]
```

Comment: You'll have to write a program, which you do not appear to have attempted to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how to. I thought about using pandas data frame to do it, but not sure how to make it the first one become B- and rest of them I-. @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

- go line by line
- if there is a digit (regex `\[\d\]`) at the end (first time), potential start of segment; mark it; also, store the ending digit; also, mark the line as "B".
- if there is a digit at the end (not first time), either another segment (check with previously stored number) which is "B", or inside current segment ("I")